# Error on selectfield which is rendered using javascript, while submitting the form in flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

the form contain two selectfield, state & city, city selectfield kept empty, because it depend on state selected choice.

for rendering this city selectfield, using javascript its worked. but while submitting the form it showed "not a valid choice"

below code shows how city field render on state selected
[html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrFVs.png)

below code response to javascripts
[python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0poT.png)

this screen show before submitting
[form display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdMUB.png)

below image show error occurred while submitting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTmou.png)

Comment: Please, add code as a code snippet, and not as an image.

Comment: this code files uploaded in github https://github.com/shivgana/customer_detail